# Is possible to achieve a "pixel perfect" positioning with React Native apps?

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework

I have an app using Ionic Framework with dozens of custom images on top of each other (layered),
SVG text elements(with custom paths) and a few javascript plugins.

I thought of porting to React Native, but couldn't get a proper place to ask other than here..

Any React developer can give some directions, if a port is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can Port your Ionic Application to React Native with Pixel Perfect UI. For a specific Platform for IOS and Android, You can also write your code. You can start with React Native latest 0.61 [React Native Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). And for Specific positioning for your SVG images, you can find several npm modules.
This is a great idea from moving your ionic App to React Native, It will give your App best performance as well as several npm packages are also available which makes its development fast and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

for height width you can use below function for every child component

```
import {PixelRatio, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

let screenWidth = Dimensions.get('screen').width;
let screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
export const DESIGN_HEIGHT_WIDTH = {HEIGHT: 736, WIDTH: 414};
/**
 *
 * @param {*} height height of the screen
 */
export const convertHeight = height => {
  const elemHeight = typeof height === 'number' ? height : parseFloat(height);
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(
    (screenHeight * elemHeight) / DESIGN_HEIGHT_WIDTH.HEIGHT,
  );
};

/**
 *
 * @param {*} width width of the screen
 */
export const convertWidth = width => {
  const elemWidth = typeof width === 'number' ? width : parseFloat(width);
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(
    (screenWidth * elemWidth) / DESIGN_HEIGHT_WIDTH.WIDTH,
  );
};
```